# Change dispatch for *all* generics

Tags: r, dispatch

## Problem

Given an object `A` wrapped in an object `E` (say an environment or list), is there a universal way to instruct R to dispatch on `A` whenever a generic is called on `E`?

## Use case

Usually contents can be represented in multiple ways and sometimes it is necessary to toggle between these representations. For instance, the sequence 1, 2, ..., 10 can be stored in a data.frame as is, or as a sequence of increments 1, 1, ..., 1.

One can come up with an implementation that stores both, e.g.

```r
E = function(view = c("cum", "incr")) {
  # Store preferred representation mode
  view <- match.arg(view) 

  # Two equivalent representations
  cum  <- data.frame(X = 1L:10L)
  incr <- data.frame(X = rep.int(1L, 10L))

  # Get preferred representation
  A <- function() {
    get(view)
  }

  # Set preferred representation mode
  setview = function(view = c("cum", "incr")) {
    view <<- match.arg(view)    
  }

  environment()
}

instance <- E()
instance$A()              # cumulative
instance$setview("incr")  
instance$A()              # incremental
```

I would like `instance` to behave like a data.frame in any reasonable respect and not like an environment, e.g. `print()`, `dim()`, ... should apply to `instance$A()` instead of `instance`.

Comment: S3? Something like `foo.eclass <- function(obj) foo(obj[["A"]])`?

Comment: Yes, S3. This applies to the generic `foo` only. How can one avoid to implement every possible method?

Comment: Do you want inheritance? Then you need to switch to S4.

Comment: I don't think that inheritance is the right thing for my issue. Please see the use case added.

Comment: I don't get it. It looks a bit like you should be working with reference classes.